# Getting Type Mismatch Error When Erasing Array

Tags: excel, vba

How do I get around this? The array is contained in a loop and needs to be cleared so that new values can be applied each run through the loop. I want to clear it before setting it. It is throwing the error the first run through when it contains no values...  thank you

```
dim array as variant

erase array
array = ws.range("a1:z1000")
```

I also tried this but get the same error:

```
dim array as variant

if array <> empty then
     erase array
end if

array = ws.range("a1:z1000")
```

Comment: Why do you need to `Erase` it? There shouldn't be any need to.

Comment: `It is throwing the error the first run through`, stack trace would be helpful with details so we could further help you.

Comment: Your `array` variable isn't an array yet.  Until you put an array in it, it's just an empty variant variable.

Comment: Alternatively, using a keyword (`array`) as a variable name may be problematic.

Comment: @ProfessorPantsless The line gives me an error because it is reading the name as the [Array function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/array-function) and wondering why I put it in a Dim statement and without arguments.

Comment: @Toddleson, good point. I just tried and I have an issue when I try to use `array` as a variable name. The OP is getting a type mismatch so it seems to not be an issue.

Comment: To avoid most naming conflicts  use a standard set of prefixes and module level types to contain module level variables.  For example I use the prefix 'my' for any variable declared in a method.  I use the prefixes ip, op and iop for method parameters to show if they are receiving, outputting or mutating respectively (this is because the BYval and Byref qualifiers for parameters are somewhat misleading).  For module/class level variables I use user defined Types of Properties and State (as the variable p and s respectively so the module level variables are qualified as s.var or p.var.

Answer (score 3):

The `If` statement is evaluating to `True` since it is treating `empty` as a variable. Use

```
If Not IsEmpty(array) then
```

instead.

Comment: Alternatively to `If Not IsEmpty(arr) Then Erase arr` you can use: `If Not TypeName(arr) = "Empty" Then Erase arr` (which btw comes close to OP's approach) or `If Not VarType(arr) = vbEmpty Then Erase arr` (where `vbEmpty` represents `0`/zero). Note that I changed the `Array` keyword to `arr` to avoid possible conflicts.